# Open file in a new tab or empty buffer

Tags: vim

I currently have the following snippet in my .vimrc:

```
command Notes tabnew ~/notes.markdown
```

This opens my notes file in a new tab. However, I'd rather make it do as follows:

- If the current buffer is empty (like when opening Vim) it should load the notes into current buffer
- If not, open a new tab

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball
```

HTH

Comment: That's an interesting start, but has some weird side-effects for me unfortunately.